# Is there a website that checks your ping from your location to a particular server using a given URL?

Tags: web, url, server, connection, ping

I've been wondering if there was a website, where you can put a particular URL and it will check your ping from your location to a particular server using a URL?

Comment: This might be covered in SuperUser, rather than StackOverflow, as it might be considered non-programming.

Comment: The question is a bit odd, as "your location" is most likely different from the server given the URL to test. So such a website would report the "ping" (or more likely the response time) from the remote server to the server serving the specified URL resource. And, if one added the "ping" from "your location" to the website the result would be of curious usefulness, as this website might be _on the other side of the world_, which pretty much defeats the purpose.

Comment: And yes, there are sites that _do_ check URLs (and response times). However, for "from your location", simply use local tooling - ping (if such is really the necessity) or the response time of a request such as can be reported in a tool like cURL or even a Developer Tools in a browser..